# ListFragment not clickable after tab change in a FragmentTabHost

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

My android app is organized in the following way:

- A FragmentTabHost containing two fragments (FragmentA in first tab and FragmentB in second tab).
- FragmentA has a ListViewFragment and inflates the following view:

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:id="@+id/titles"
     android:name="br.sachetto.ondepublicar.ListViewFragment"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent" 
     android:focusable="false"
     android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
     android:clickable="false" />
  ```
- Fragment B has a very similar view.
- The following code is used to load the view in FragmentA:

  ```
  private static View view;

  @Override 
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
                           Bundle savedInstanceState) {           

          if (view != null) {         
                  ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();        
                  if (parent != null)             
                          parent.removeView(view);    
                  }     
                  else {  
                          view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_fragment, 
                                                  container, false);  
                  }
           }  
      return view;         
  }
  ```

Everything works fine until I change from first tab (FragmentA) to second tab (FragmentB).
After this change, my list view stop responding for click events. But if I scroll down and 
up the list it starts to respond again.
Can anybody help me if this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken you inflate a fragment in to a fragment which was previously (in xml) defined as static/compile time fragment.

This practice is not allowed and can cause two fragments to be on top of each other. I'd recommend you to inflate all of you fragment which will be moved or changed dynamically via code.

Comment: You are right, this is not allowed. My main idea is to make a title detail app like explained here: [Using-Fragments-to-Build-User-Interfaces-in-Android](http://developer.samsung.com/android/technical-docs/Using-Fragments-to-Build-User-Interfaces-in-Android). This is why I put a fragment inside other. The biggest problem is that the tabHost only accepts fragments. Otherwise I would make FragmentA as a FragmentActivity. Is there a way to make this without using nested fragments?

Comment: I found a solution based on nested fragments: http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#NestedFragments